# Effect of Nested Item's line-height on Parent With Identical line-height

Tags: html, css, layout

In the following example, both the button and the icon within it have the same `line-height`, however the icon forces the button's `height` to become greater than its `line-height`. By reducing the `font-size` or `line-height` of the icon this extra height is removed from the button. Why is this? Why does a nested with the same `line-height` result in the `height` of the element which contains it increasing?

*Note: I'm not looking for a hack to fix it, but to understand why it's happening.*

```css
.Button,
.Button-icon {
  line-height: 68px;
}

.Button {
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: none;
}

.Button-icon {
  line-height: 68px;
  font-size: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button class="Button">
   Sad Face <span class="Button-icon">☹</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Not even sure it's a nesting thing: Line-height is not the same as height and, in any case, implementation is buggy on buttons - See [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)

Comment: @Paulie_D If you remove the icon, you'll see the button's height is the same as its line-height (at least in Chrome). The presence of the icon does appear to be the issue.